# Simple web gui for python script without side web server

Tags: python, ajax, webserver, web-frontend

For example, simple while loop, with control in the browser:

python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import time

Delay = 1 # Default

while True:
    seed = random.random()
    time.sleep( Delay )
    # Show seed in browser
```

While `while loop` works, I want to see random seed each second in web browser and ability to change `Delay` without reloading page, ajax interface.

I'm trying to choose true way here: [wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), methinks that django framework is too huge for such easy task.

Comment: You can use a micro-framework Flask or a lightweight framework WSGIServlets.

Comment: Could you show me example of solution for my task?

Comment: Look under the section `What is it` at this link https://code.google.com/p/wsgiservlets/ and you can find a very simple example there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and lightweight framework [WSGIServlets](https://code.google.com/p/wsgiservlets/)

Hello world example:

```
from wsgiservlets import *
class helloworld(HTMLPage):    
  def write_content(self):        
    self.writeln("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: I'm talking about interactive `while loop` on the server side.

Comment: You can modify the above code to include `while loop`. Interactive generally means input from users. Or did you say that you want to animate seed coming from server?

Comment: Yes, I want to have web iface without reloading for any get/post, interactive & real-time, with animated `seed` and ability to change `Delay` just by prompt only, without page reloading.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you wanted. Have you tried any lightweight framework like WSGIServlets yet to see what you wanted?

Comment: WSGIServlets required to reload page, as I can see, there is no ajax.

Comment: So, I suppose you can add ajax code. Or don't you want to use ajax at all?

Comment: Looks like with wsgiservlets, I can't add ajax. Am I right? If no, could you give me example.

Comment: Are you new to HTML/JS stuffs? On the other hand, if you know HTML/JS well, then without any server-side things, you can easily develop similar things in pure HTML/JS before moving the logic to server side. Is it clear enough for you to understand?

Comment: I'm not a pro in HTML/JS stuff. I'm looking for responsive web iface for just python script, without side web-server like apache.

Comment: What do you mean by `side web server`? For a file containing executable scripts (of python in your case), you need an interpreter, which is already available on your machine. But to render it on browser, you need something like server to serve web page. Are you avoiding server-like thing because it is physically remote from you? If so, then you can setup it on your machine.

Comment: No, I'm just looking for a way to implement cross-platform gui for python script. Available on port 8080 ajax web iface to script could change state of script and retrieve data from script automatically without reloading, like cgi&ajax doing the same with apache.